# gRPC traffic via cloudflare

Tags: grpc, cloudflare

I have a gRPC server hosted on my private server. I exposed it to the public network by creating tunnels using cloudflare tunnels.

But so far I have been unsuccessful in connecting to the server.

I came across some resources that states that the tunnel doesn't support gRPC. But there are some other resources as well which states gRPC is supported but no tutorial on how to set it up.

I tried creating a tunnel and setting up public hostnames with unix, tcp, http, https. It didnt work for me.